# Не получается вывести ответ сервера в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkrequest

```
QUrl url = "http://dt.miet.ru//ppo_it/api/" + city + "/" +area +"/" +house + "/" + apartament; //сшиваем запрос
QNetworkRequest request(url); //создаем запрос
QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(request); //отправляем
ui->label_6->setText(reply->readAll()); //выводим ответ
```

в url все сшиваемые переменные типа QString, а manager уже созданный объект класса QNetworkAccessManager.

По идее, сервер возвращает ответ в .json - может ли это влиять на результат, если да, то помогите исправить?

Comment: 1) в readAll() действительно есть данные? можно их кусок увидеть? 2) ui->label_6 это действительно элемент label? 3) проверял запись в любой другой элемент интерфейса, типа text input?

Comment: QDebug()<<reply->readAll(); Что-то выводит?

Comment: Проверил label_6 она существует, если ты об этом) Про readAll я так понял ты имеешь ввиду есть ли в ответе сервера что-нибудь? Извиняюсь если туплю, недавно с кьютом работаю(

Comment: Про QDebug не совсем понял, куда эту штуку? Подключил библиотеку с ним "QDebug" но все равно ошибка сборки, говорит элемента нет такого

Comment: `qDebug()<<reply->readAll();`, выводит в консоль IDE если из IDE запущено или просто в консоль

Comment: спасибо завтра посмотрю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QNetworkReply`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html) — это асинхронный интерфейс, объект-*promise* («*обещание*»). Когда он создаётся никаких данных в нём нет, это просто «контракт», по которому можно получить результат работы, когда он появится. т.е. вместо того чтобы сразу делать `readAll()` сначала нужно дождаться сигнала `finished()`:

```
//..
QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(request); //отправляем
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, 
        [this, reply] () {
          if (reply->error()) {
            QMessageBox::critical (this, QString::fromUtf8("Покайтесь в грехах!"),
                QString::fromUtf8("Ошибка %1: %2")
                   .arg((int)reply->error())
                   .arg(reply->errorString()));
          }
          ui->label_6->setText(QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll()));

          reply->deleteLater();
        });
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, теперь вроде все норм) буду признателен если подскажите как закрыть вопрос)

Comment: @Fungor, Слева от ответа должна быть галочка...

Comment: помоги еще раз, пж: при запуске нормальной ссылки, по которой на питоне получается ответ, это приложение вывод ошибку 3. Такого кода http ошибки не нашел, что делать?

Comment: @Fungor, это свой [код QNetworkReply](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#NetworkError-enum). В данном случае — `HostNotFound`... осмысленное сообщение вместо кода можно получить с помощью `errorString()`...

Comment: Спасибо бро от души